# Symfony: dynamic form with embded form

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I've a main form (StrainType) that is inherited by StrainGmoType, and StrainGmoType embded a StrainPlasmidType.

In the main form (StrainType), I've a field where the user choose a team, then some fields depends on this choice (in the main, the child, and embded forms). For all fields declared in the main form or child, it works. But I've 2 CollectionType, in this CollectionType I've ManyToMany Relation with Argument. Then I've do a specific Type (StrainPlasmidType), and in the main and child type I call them in a CollectionType (in the example only in the child)). But, I can't get the team field in this type, then I can't do PRE_SET_DATA, PRE_SUBMIT or POST_SUBMIT...

I've try to use inherit_data, but it's not adapted for this case. How can I get the data of the team field in the StrainPlasmidType ?

A part of the code:

The StrainForm:

```
  class StrainType extends AbstractType
  {
      public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
      {
          $builder
              ->add('team', EntityType::class, [
                  'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Team',
                  'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                      return $er->createQueryBuilder('team')
                          ->leftJoin('team.members', 'members')
                          ->leftJoin('team.projects', 'projects')
                          ->leftJoin('projects.members', 'project_members')
                          ->where('members = :user')
                          ->orWhere('project_members = :user')
                          ->setParameter('user', $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser());
                  },
                  'data' => $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser()->getFavoriteTeam(),
                  'choice_label' => 'name',
                  'placeholder' => '-- select a team --',
                  'mapped' => false,
              ])
```

The GmoStrain form:

```
  class StrainGmoType extends AbstractType
  {
      public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
      {
          $builder
              ->add('strainPlasmids', CollectionType::class, [
                  'entry_type' => StrainPlasmidType::class,
                  'allow_add' => true,
                  'allow_delete' => true,
                  'by_reference' => false,
                  'required' => false,
              ])

              //...

        public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
        {
            $resolver->setDefaults([
                'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Strain',
            ]);
        }

        public function getParent()
        {
            return StrainType::class;
        }
    }
```

The StrainPlasmidType:

```
  class StrainPlasmidType extends AbstractType
  {
      public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
      {
          $builder
              ->add('plasmid', EntityType::class, [
                  'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Plasmid',
                  'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                      return $er->createQueryBuilder('p')
                          ->leftJoin('p.team', 'team')
                          ->leftJoin('team.members', 'members')
                          ->where('members = :user')
                          ->setParameter('user', $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser())
                          ->orderBy('p.autoName', 'ASC')
                      ;
                  },
                  'group_by' => function (Plasmid $plasmid) {
                      return $plasmid->getTeam()->getName();
                  },
                  'choice_label' => function (Plasmid $plasmid) {
                      return $plasmid->getAutoName().' - '.$plasmid->getName();
                  },
                  'placeholder' => '-- select a plasmid --',
              ])
              ->add('state', ChoiceType::class, [
                  'choices' => [
                      'Replicative' => 'replicative',
                      'Integrated' => 'integrated',
                      'Cured' => 'cured',
                  ],
                  'placeholder' => '-- select a state --',
              ])
          ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I just use options of the form to send the data to the embed form:

In the main:

```
  $form->add('strainPlasmids', CollectionType::class, [
      'entry_type' => StrainPlasmidType::class,
      'entry_options' => [
          'parent_data' => $team,
      ],
      'allow_add' => true,
      'allow_delete' => true,
      'by_reference' => false,
      'required' => false,
  ]);
```

And, in the embed form:

```
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
      $builder
          ->add('plasmid', EntityType::class, [
              'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Plasmid',
              'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($options) {
                  return $er->createQueryBuilder('p')
                      ->leftJoin('p.team', 'team')
                      ->where('team = :team')
                      ->setParameter('team', $options['parent_data'])
                      ->orderBy('p.autoName', 'ASC')
                  ;
              },

  public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
  {
      $resolver->setDefaults([
          'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\StrainPlasmid',
      ]);

      $resolver->setRequired(array('parent_data'));
  }
```